# Mongoose Aggregation not working, tried different ways still not able to solve the problem, even dont know what is problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am new to node and mongoose. Tried many ways though none worked for me.

1. **Aggregate query on mongo shell is working, here is query**:-

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      p_id: ObjectId("5d8b4f24d86d9f2400d7ff46"),
      m_id: { $in: [ObjectId("5dde14b3f34ac02500a2b0aa")] }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { updated_at: 1 } },
  { $group: { _id: "$m_id", evaluation: { $last: "$evaluation" } } }
]);
```

2. **Aggregate query in mongoose**:-

```js
Model.aggregate([
  { $match: { p_id: pId, m_id: { $in: mIds } } },
  { $sort: { updated_at: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$m_id",
      evaluation: { $last: "$evaluation" }
    }
  }
]);
```

Error:-  **throwing cursor option is required**

3. **Aggregate query after adding cursor optionr:-**

Query:-

```js
Model.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: { p_id: pId, m_id: { $in: mIds } } },
    { $sort: { updated_at: 1 } },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$m_id",
        evaluation: { $last: "$evaluation" }
      }
    }
  ],
  { cursor: {} }
);
```

Error: - **error_stack=Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators**

4. **Mongoose aggregate api fluent returning aggregationcursor but on doing aggregationcursor.next() a promise is returned in pending state. After adding then() on aggregationcursor.next() a null object is returned:-**

```js
Model.aggregate()
  .match({ p_id: pId, m_id: { $in: mIds } })
  .sort({ $updated_at: 1 })
  .group({
    _id: "$m_id",
    evaluation: { $last: "$evaluation" }
  })
  .cursor({ batchSize: 1000 });
```

Schema:

```js
const PSchema = new Schema({
  m_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  p_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  evaluation: { type: String, enum: _.values(EvaluationType) },
  created_at: { type: Date },
  updated_at: { type: Date }
});
```

> ```
> Mongo/Mongoose version:-
> "@types/mongoose": "^3.8.36",
> "mongodb": "^3.3.5",
> "mongoose": "~4.5.9",
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to try different things, finally following query worked for me.

```
let cursor = Model.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
     'p_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(providerId) ,'m_id': { $in:objectIds } 
    } 
  },
  {
    $sort: { 
      'updated_at':1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$m_id',
      evaluation: { $last: '$evaluation' }
    }
  }
]).cursor({async:true});
```

Three things which i had to do:

1. I have to pass objectIds only in $match, as in normal find strings work, mongoose is able to convert strings into objectIds internally. For aggregate have to pass objectIds in $match.
2. Have to pass cursor option. As per [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate][1] cursor is mandatory after mongodb 3.6 version in aggregate. My mongodb version id 4.0.5 .
3. Had to pass cursor in async mode *cursor({async:true})*. Got results from cursor as cursor.toArray().